# Circuit analysis problem contribution from an AC source

Tags: circuit-analysis

I need help to find the method to find the solution of this problem.
In the following circuit, we cancel U1 and we need to find the tension u_4_2 going through R4 contributed by of the source u_2(t).

[image]

The answer should be: u_4_2(t) = 1.08sin(2 pi f t) V

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the circuit we want to analyze is given by:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faLRy2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_3=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_4-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_4-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

So, we can solve for \$\displaystyle\text{V}_4\$:

$$\text{V}_4=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1\text{V}_2+\text{R}_2\text{V}_1\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag4$$

Now, when using your values we get:

$$\text{V}_4\left(t\right)=\frac{\displaystyle1000\left(15\cdot6\sin\left(4000\pi t\right)+50\cdot5\right)}{\displaystyle15\left(50+270+1000\right)+50\left(270+1000\right)}\tag5$$

Which, when simplified gives:

$$\text{V}_4\left(t\right)=\frac{2500}{833}+\frac{900}{833}\cdot\sin\left(4000\pi t\right)\approx3.0012+1.08043\sin\left(12566.4 t\right)\tag6$$

Comment: Jan, you know we don't give complete answers to homework questions where the OP didn't show any effort?

Comment: @Transistor I apologize for not demonstrating my efforts initially. It was not intended as a lack of effort or in bad faith. I refrained from detailing all the attempts I made to avoid adding unnecessary clutter to the question. Interestingly, I managed to resolve the issue independently earlier today, employing a different approach, before coming across Jan Eerland's solution.

link to a screenshot of my notes : https://i.imgur.com/2FhoBNr.png

Comment: @JanEerland thanks for taking the time and for the detailed response! I appreciate it a lot.